# Push Notification from WooCommerce site to Flutter application

Tags: wordpress, flutter, woocommerce, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am stuck at one point and need help to resolve the issue.
I tried many ***plugins*** but none of them fulfil my requirements. I am developing an E-Commerce user app in Flutter which link with our WordPress WooCommerce site using **WooCommerce rest APIs**. I need to integrate **push notifications** into my application but most of the plugins are offer push notification facilities only when you publish a post.

**My Basic Requirements:**
I need to notify

- *when users place an order*
- *when order status updates*
- *when new coupons are added*

Comment: Hello did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Hi.
yes there is only one way to resolve this and that is create/add hooks.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need **back-end** developer. Because some plugins are only provide service for **posts & products**. But non of them offer services for orders. So we need to create **custom hoods** to achieve this functionality.

I hope you understand it.

***Best of Luck!***

Comment: So I create my django backend and from woocommerce call my django api and from django send a notifications to users with the help of firebase?

Comment: No, you need to add functionality in woo-commerce using core PHP. like, create a custom plugin for woo-commerce to achieve this functionality.
Hope you understand.